# Detecting unicode chars of asian languages typed to UITextfield

Tags: ios, encoding, nsstring, uitextfield, char

The Messages app of iOS detects if the user has typed a unicode char depending on the input language.If you change to any of the asien languages you see that maximum number of chars to be write his limited to 70 instead of 160. Meanwhile if you input a smiley which is also encoded as unicode it only takes 2 char value. My problem is how to i detect the unicode chars that would limit my maximum message length to 70?

Answer (score 1):

To detect the current language of the keyboard refer here 
[Detecting unicode chars of asian languages typed to UITextfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841777/detecting-unicode-chars-of-asian-languages-typed-to-uitextfield)

For dynamic calculation converting the string to nsdata and looking for size should work.

```
NSLog(@"%i", [@"a" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding].length);
```

gives me 1

```
NSLog(@"%i", [@"aa" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding].length);
```

gives me 2

```
NSLog(@"%i", [@"aö" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding].length);
```

gives me 3

```
NSLog(@"%i", [@"草" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding].length);
```

gives me 3

edit:

What do you mean with take 1 space?
From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

The first 128 characters (US-ASCII) need one byte. The next 1,920 characters need two bytes to encode. This covers the remainder of almost all Latin-derived alphabets, and also Greek, Cyrillic, Coptic, Armenian, Hebrew, Arabic, Syriac and Tāna alphabets, as well as Combining Diacritical Marks. Three bytes are needed for characters in the rest of the Basic Multilingual Plane (which contains virtually all characters in common use). Four bytes are needed for characters in the other planes of Unicode, which include less common CJK characters and various historic scripts and mathematical symbols.

You can check your strings like this if they are containing any chars from specific unicode sets

> NSRange range = NSMakeRange(256, range.length -1);

```
NSLog(@"%i", [@"ı" rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet
                                            characterSetWithRange:range]].location == NSNotFound);
NSLog(@"%i", [@"ö" rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet
                                            characterSetWithRange:range]].location == NSNotFound);
NSLog(@"%i", [@"ab" rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet
                                            characterSetWithRange:range]].location == NSNotFound);
```

Comment: yes good approach but the problem is some of the emoojies has length of 4 and some 2 in utf8.I need to detect number of unicorn chars not he length.

Comment: Unicorn chars :)  Some of them have lenght of 4 and some 2 and you don't need length but number of unicode chars? What do you mean exactly can you give me some examples? AFAIK The emojies are not more then just normal text. But they are presented in sender and receiver as icons. So you can work with them just like normal text.

Comment: the problem is that i have a counter whihc need to be incremented according to type of unicode char.For example the japanese unicode chars will take 1 space and emojii will tkae 2.I want to implmenet the same behaviour of messaging app of IOS.As soon as it detects a unicode char it restricts the number of allowed chars to 70.in this casse i need to handle the unicode chars individually.How can i extract only one unicode char out of nstring?substringWithRange does only take the first half of unicode

Comment: yes but also with this approach substringWithRange to get one char will only take the first half of 4 byte chars.A smiley looks like this \uXXX1\uXXX2 how do you make sure that \uXXX1 is not handled apart from \uXXX2.This is my only problem.Then i already have a parser that makes the calculation.

Comment: because for me it makes a different if it is a greek letter or smiley